# Loading Bulk XML data into oracle

Tags: xml

So here goes all.. I'm having a large XML data which i need to import into oracle.

I have searched Google to my best and found that we need to create tables according to the xml fields and then import it. But I need to know if its possible that table fields will be created automatically with XML fields. because im not sure of the number of fields in xml. please let me knowhHow to do this..